# Aggregate Merge Lookup Result to Main Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I created a function to stitch 2 records from different collections:

Colection 1 record:

```
{
    _id: objectId(1231242331233),
    acc: '12390',
    val2: 'asdasdas'
}
```

Collection 2 record:

```
{
    _id: objectId(989232382302308),
    isValid: '1',
    tf: '098789928',
    acc: '12390'
}
```

For this I came up with the following aggregate function with a $lookup.

```
Collection2.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "Collection1",
            localField: "acc",
            foreignField: "acc",
            as: "acc_record"
        }
    }   
    {
        $out: 'Collection3'
    }
]);
```

This generates a Collection3 with records that have the following structure:

```
{
    _id: objectId(989232382302308),
    isValid: '1',
    tf: '098789928',
    acc: '12390',
    acc_record:[
        {
            _id: objectId(1231242331233),
            acc: '12390',
            val2: 'asdasdas'
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the aggregate function to merge these 2 records but instead of placing the Collection1 record in a deeper level of the json object place the non equal elements only and merge the ones that have the same name?

so the final record result would be:

```
{
        _id: objectId(989232382302308),
        isValid: '1',
        tf: '098789928',
        acc: '12390',
        val2: 'asdasdas'
}
```

Comment: @NeilLunn just forgot to accept it at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
Collection2.aggregate([
    { "$lookup":{
      "from": "Collection1",
      "localField": "acc",
      "foreignField": "acc",
      "as": "acc_record"
    }},
    { "$project": {
      "isValid": 1,
      "tf": 1,
      "acc": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$acc_record.acc",0] },
      "val2": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$acc_record.val2", 0] }
    }},
    { "$out": "Collection3" }
]);
```

And use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to reference the values from the array and promote them as values in the top level object.

That's fine if you always know the results are "one to one" and can simply take the values from the first array element returned. If they are "one to many", then you apply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as well:

```
Collection2.aggregate([
    { "$lookup":{
      "from": "Collection1",
      "localField": "acc",
      "foreignField": "acc",
      "as": "acc_record"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$acc_record" },
    { "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "isValid": 1,
      "tf": 1,
      "acc": "$acc_record.acc",
      "val2": "$acc_record.val2"
    }},
    { "$out": "Collection3" }
]);
```

Which is also perfectly valid for "one to one", but you should take note that the `_id` is "deliberately" removed here. The reason is that with "many" results the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) produces "multiple" copies of the parent document for each array member returned in the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result. Since `_id` is the "primary key", you cannot keep that value as being the same in "multiple documents".

So the point of discarding the primary key is so that [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) can create a new value on writing and not fail with "duplicate key errors". Alternately if you wanted to keep this as a "reference", then simply rename the `"$_id"` value to another field within the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

---

For larger output, we can use some tricks to "merge" where your MongoDB supports the features. In current releases these are [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) from MongoDB 3.4.4 and upwards:

```
Collection2.aggregate([
    { "$lookup":{
      "from": "Collection1",
      "localField": "acc",
      "foreignField": "acc",
      "as": "acc_record"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$acc_record" },
    { "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
              "cond": { "$not": { "$in":  ["$$this.k", ["_id", "acc_record"] } }
            }},
            { "$filter": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$acc_record" },
              "cond": { "$ne": ["$$this.k", "acc"] }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$out": "Collection3" }
])
```

The trick is to turn both the "ROOT" document and the sub-array content into separate arrays, filtering out the overlapping keys and and apply [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to make them into one array. Then you can apply [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) on the "joined" result and turn this into the root document via [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/).

### MongoDB 3.6

MongoDB 3.6 makes it easier still and introduces [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/), so then you can really do something as simple as:

```
Collection2.aggregate([
    { "$lookup":{
      "from": "Collection1",
      "localField": "acc",
      "foreignField": "acc",
      "as": "acc_record"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$acc_record" },
    { "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          { "$arrayToObject": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
              "cond": { "$not": { "$in":  ["$$this.k", ["_id", "acc_record","acc"] } },
            }
          },
          "$acc_record"
        ]
      }
    }},
    { "$out": "Collection3" }
]);
```

Where generally you still want to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the keys that you don't want, such as the target field name of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and most probably the `"localField"` or `"foreignField"` values as well. So you can't really just use `"$ROOT"` to merge with the sub-key's content unless you are prepared to add yet another aggregation stage to remove that sub-key altogether.

So generally speaking the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) does not really add much here, other than of course the naming of the operator makes the intention of the code crystal clear.

Comment: Do I need to reference all the records in Collection2 in the $project? Collection2 representation there is just an example being that my actual collection is composed by records with over 50 properties. Making this work cumbersome.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins Still writing. I'm getting to that. And in future you actually need to specify details like that "in your question".

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins Done. Those are the complete ways to do this using `$out`. Anything else you take the cursor and iterate it to transform the output then write back.